# Can't access Flask session variable inside flask_socketio app

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I am having the problem that as in the code below, I have several variables inside my session variable in my flask app. I would like to use them inside my socket_ip routes but nothing appears when I try to print my variable session. I see "key 1". Can anyone pls explain me why this happens and if there is a way for me to access my session variables inside the drawer function. TIA.

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socket_io = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
   session["key1"] = "var1"

@socket_io.on('dataReceiver')
def drawer():
   print(session["key1"])
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation regarding how the session is handled by Flask-SocketIO?